# Voicemails not being intercepted by Google Voice

Tags: iphone, google-voice

I have a Google Voice account that is set to transcribe voicemails and send them as e-mail. This used to work on my iPhone 4.

I upgraded to the iPhone 4S and do not receive voicemail to my Google Voice account anymore. All voicemail goes to my Visual Voicemail.

How can I make my voicemails go to Google Voice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you must setup Google voicemail for every unique device. Have you tried deactivating and reactivating Google voicemail for your phone? This can be done through the Google Voice website under Settings: http://google.com/voice?pli=1#phones.